Extracting a subsequence common to infinitely many sets from an uncountable collection with uniform positive upper density
Let $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$ be strictly increasing sequence of positive integers satisfying $a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<a_3<b_3<\ldots$ and $(b_n-a_n) \to \infty$. Define $I_n:= [a_n,b_n]$, meaning the set of all consecutive integers from $a_n$ to $b_n$.. Let $A_{\alpha},\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$ be an uncountable family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the following:
There exists some $c \in (0,1)$ so that for all $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$ there exists some $n(\alpha) \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|A_{\alpha} \cap I_n|\geq c(b_n-a_n)$ for all $n\geq n(\alpha)$. (Here $|B|$ is the number of elements of a finite subset $B \subset \mathbb{N}$)
Then my question is the following:
Does there exist a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $\{l_n\} \to \infty$ for which there exists an infinite subset $\mathcal{B}\subset \mathcal{A}$ so that  $l_n \in A_{\alpha}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$?

Yes. If one can find some infinite subset $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A}$ so that intersection of $A_{\alpha}$ over $\alpha \in \mathcal{B}$ is infinite, that would answer the question. Also I have already posted the question to overflow@bof

Although I have taken the $I_n$ to be disjoint. What you said would seem to prove  a stronger result, right? @bof And could you clarify what $\omega_1$ is. Sorry but I am not familiar with this notation.

@bof: Great question. --- I saw this question yesterday and initially, before reading the details, I thought it might be something discussed in this 13 May 2005 sci.math post. Then I noticed the intersections were to be finite sets, and decided this is likely not something I know anything about or had time to give sufficient thought to, but I did upvote the question - 1st upvote, I think (if not, then 2nd). At the time there was a close vote, and I couldn't figure out why. Maybe lacking context for how the question arose?

This question was crossposted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/471638/ and answers have been posted there.

The answer is yes. This answer is also posted at Math Overflow, where the question was crossposted.
Theorem. Let $A$ be an index set, $|A|=\aleph_1$. Let $I_n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$) be disjoint countable sets with $I=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}I_n$, and let $\mu$ be a nonnegative finitely additive measure on $I$ such that $\mu(I_n)\lt\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Let $\mathcal U$ be a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$ and let $\varepsilon\gt0$. For each $\alpha\in A$ let $S_\alpha$ be a set such that
$$\{n\in\mathbb N:\mu(S_\alpha\cap I_n)\gt\varepsilon\mu(I_n)\}\in\mathcal U$$
(so in particular $|S_\alpha\cap I|=\aleph_0$).
Then there is an infinite set $M\subseteq A$ such that $(\bigcap_{\alpha\in M}S_\alpha)\cap I_n\ne\varnothing$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$.
Proof.
Claim 1. There exist $n_0\in\mathbb N$, $x_0\in I_{n_0}$, $B\subseteq A$, $J_n\subseteq I_n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$), and $J\subseteq I$ such that $|B|=\aleph_1$, $J=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}J_n$,
$$\forall\alpha\in B,\ \{n\in\mathbb N:\mu(S_\alpha\cap J_n)\gt\varepsilon\mu(J_n)\}\in\mathcal U,$$
$x_0\in S_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in B$, and $I_{n_0}\cap J=\varnothing.$
Proof of Claim 1. Choose $x_0\in I$ so that $\{\alpha\in A:x_0\in S_\alpha\}$ is uncountable. (If there were no such $x_0$ then, since $I$ is countable and $A$ is uncountable, there would be some $\alpha\in A$ with $S_\alpha\cap I=\varnothing$.) Then $x_0\in I_{n_0}$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb N$. Let $B=\{\alpha\in A:x_0\in S_\alpha\}$, let $J_n=I_n\setminus I_{n_0}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, and let $J=I\setminus I_{n_0}$.
Claim 2. There exist $\alpha_0\in A$, $B\subseteq A\setminus\{\alpha_0\}$, $J_n\subseteq I_n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$), $J\subseteq I$, and $\delta\gt0$ such that $|B|=\aleph_1$, $J=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}J_n\subseteq S_{\alpha_0}$, and
$$\forall\beta\in B,\ \{n\in\mathbb N:\mu(S_\beta\cap J_n)\gt\delta\mu(J_n)\}\in\mathcal U.$$
Proof of Claim 2. Choose $k\in\mathbb N$ so that $k\varepsilon\gt1$ and choose $\delta\gt0$ so that $k\varepsilon-\binom k2\delta\gt1$. Let's call $S_\alpha$ and $S_\beta$ "almost disjoint" if $\{n\in\mathbb N:\mu(S_\alpha\cap S_\beta\cap I_n)\le\delta\mu(I_n)\}\in\mathcal U$. Then any pairwise almost disjoint subfamily of $\{S_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ has fewer than $k$ elements, so there is a maximal pairwise almost disjoint subfamily $\{S_\alpha:\alpha\in A_0\}$ where $A_0$ is a finite subset of $A$. Then for each $\beta\in A\setminus A_0$ there is some $\alpha\in A_0$ such that $\{n\in\mathbb N:\mu(S_\beta\cap S_\alpha\cap I_n)\gt\delta\mu(I_n)\}\in\mathcal U$. Choose $\alpha_0\in A_0$ and $B\subseteq A\setminus A_0$ so that $|B|=\aleph_1$ and
$$\forall\beta\in B,\ \{n\in\mathbb N:\mu(S_\beta\cap S_{\alpha_0}\cap I_n)\gt\delta\mu(I_n)\ge\delta\mu(S_{\alpha_0}\cap I_n)\}\in\mathcal U.$$
Let $J_n=S_{\alpha_0}\cap I_n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$), and let $J=S_{\alpha_0}\cap I$.
Applying Claims 1 and 2 infinitely many times, we get infinitely many distinct elements $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\dots\in A$ and $x_0,x_1,\dots\in I$ and $n_0,n_1,\dots\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_k\in S_j\cap I_{n_k}$ for all $j,k\in\mathbb N$.
